# How dangerous duels were?

Tags: cultural-history, death

I know that duels (in the form popular in Europe of XIX and early XX century) didn't always end in death (dueling to death was even prohibited by some code e.g. Boziewicz code). I would like to know however if we have any statistics about how exactly dangerous duels were. How high were the odds of being killed when entering a duel. Also it would be good to know which type of duel (fencing or shooting) was more dangerous.

Comment: When? I would imagine the answer changes drastically between say 1400 and 1850.

Comment: @zefciu - I am going to close this question for now because it is too broad and general. If you would like to reword it and give it a more narrow focus, I'll be happy to conisder reopening it.

Comment: Tycho Brahe lost his nose in a duel so I'd guess it came with some dangers...

Comment: @Russel ...and Pushkin died in a duel. I know some stories from history and literature about people engaging in duels being sometimes killed, sometimes wounded. But I would like a statistic that would say "the odds of one of persons dying in the duel at the beginning of XX century was x per cent".

Comment: ...as did Alexander Hamilton. President Andrew Jackson killed at least one man in a duel (its tough to get a complete count of how many he participated in).

Comment: I have edited the question as suggested. However it still isn't open. Is there anything else I should do?